# вернуть правда/ложь в процедуре sql

Tags: sql

Я хочу вернуть значение true/false из процедуры. Чтоб базироваться на проверке.

> ===> если Вася 255, то он Админ = правда.

я [нашла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825620/how-to-return-bool-from-stored-proc), что можно вернуть значение в бите, постаралсь применить в своем решении, используя [тесты](https://sql.sh/cours/case) условий (when/case)

вот моя процедура `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBooleanAdminStatut
    
    @SomeProperty int, @bit BIT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT MyTable.SomeProperty2
    
    case MyTable.SomeProperty2
        when 255 then set @bit = 1
        else set @bit = 0
    end 

    from MyTable 
    
    where SomeProperty = @SomeProperty

END
GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я получаю ошибку синтаксиса, где я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Ошибку прикрепите, вероятно там и находится ответ на Ваш вопрос

Comment: @StepanTurbasov ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: Вынесите set наружу: `set @bit = case ... when ... then 1 else 0 end`.

Comment: @insolor ща попробую это тоже протестировать, потому что мне так наглядно ясней, когда переменая выхода при декларации

Comment: @insolor не получилось☹️, я и в скобки засунула `set @bit = (case...when) from` => у меня from подчеркнут и в select, я уверена, какая то мелочь синтаксиса. Ну да ладно, нашла решение работает, ниже ответ ✅

Answer (score 0, accepted):

условие выборки заключила в скобки, и убрала возврат при декларации, а просто как показано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377781/return-boolean-value-on-sql-select-statement) `cast`-ом вернула значение, работает ок✅

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBooleanAdminStatut
    
    @SomeProperty int

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(select MyTable.SomeProperty2 from MyTable 
where SomeProperty = @SomeProperty and MyTable.SomeProperty2 = 255)   
    
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END as AdminState

END
GO
```

Comment: а `case` то тут зачем? exists и так булевый предикат

Comment: @teran не знаю, я ссылку в ответе оставила, код оттуда скопировала

Comment: Попробую во вторник убрать case отпишусь потом как работает и выдает ли ожидаемый результат

Comment: @teran тут же Case по типу if else ? если убрать case, то как сделать, там же цепочка ошибку выдаст синтаксическую. ===> я насколько поняла в скобках я говорю, если это условие верно верни мне один или ноль. вы можете пояснить изменения повторения без case

Comment: `SELECT EXISTS(....) as AdminState`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270682/13754729

Comment: вот так https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-return-bool-from-stored-proc тоже попробовала, все равно ошибка синтаксиса